# Does CocoaPod use_frameworks! work with iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I want to use a Podfile like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

Will this work with iOS 7? I thought that frameworks are only available in iOS 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use:

`use_frameworks!`

with iOS7.

Comment: So, to make it clear, this means that you cannot build a project that supports iOS 7+ in Swift using CocoaPods, right?

Answer (score 14):

No it does not. `use_frameworks!` enables Swift support by building your code in the new [dynamic frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824913/where-can-one-find-apple-documentation-pertaining-to-dynamic-frameworks-for-ios). Dynamic frameworks only support iOS 8. Unfortunately, since you cannot use Swift in static libraries (the previous way CocoaPods bundled libraries), this was the only way to bundle Swift files.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: It turned out, you can actually deploy dynamic frameworks on iOS 7. Not via Cocoapods, probably, though. Instructions (thanks, @user102008!): [Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3). This update doesn't really answer the original question, but it was added to clarify my old answer based on a new information.

---

A note that, I believe, is important enough to be an answer. Dynamic frameworks are actually supported on iOS 7, and you can run code using dynamic frameworks on an iOS 7 device. **However** iOS 7 doesn't support fair-play encrypted third-party frameworks. And because of that if you tried to submit an app for iOS7 using dynamic frameworks to iTunesConnect, it would be rejected ([one prooflink](https://github.com/CocoaPods/swift/issues/9#issuecomment-66925111)).

I think that it is important, because it might seem that it works, but it doesn't. And if you ignore the warning, you might encounter the problem too late, when half the project is already in Swift.

We faced this problem when we were starting to develop our own pod. The project compiled and ran fine on iOS 7. Good thing we researched this issue further.

Comment: "if you tried to submit an app for iOS7 using dynamic frameworks to iTunesConnect, it would be rejected" It's not true that an app submitted to the app store targetting iOS 7 cannot have dynamic frameworks. Yes, it will be rejected if the app links to the dynamic framework at build time. But [Apple provides instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3) for how to not link it at build time but dynamically link it at runtime using `dlopen` only when running on iOS 8+.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks! I didn't know that. Good to know. I updated the answer to include this information.